# Firebase Auth -> user created with signInWithCustomToken has no email address

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am using Firebase Custom Authentication System for a mobile app made with Ionic and I use Laravel 5.2 as a custom Auth back-end.

When new user is registered I generate a token in laravel (using firebase/php-jwt) and return it to the mobile app.

During this register process the app receive the token and create a user on firebase using the following code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken($auth.getToken())
    .then(function(response) {
        $log.debug(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        $log.debug(error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
    });
```

On back-end I use the code below to generate the token:

```
private function create_custom_token($uid, $email, $is_premium_account) {
    $service_account_email = env('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'); 
    $private_key = env('SERVICE_PRIVATE_KEY');

    $now_seconds = time();
    $payload = array(
        "iss" => $service_account_email,
        "sub" => $service_account_email,
        "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
        "iat" => $now_seconds,
        "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
        "uid" => $uid,
        "claims" => array(
            "premium_account" => $is_premium_account,
            "email" => $email,
        )
    );
    return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
}
```

As you can see on the image below the user is generated on firebase but the problem is that it has no email address, only a UID.

[image]

It will be much better to have the email address in order to easily identify users.

Maybe someone cane help. Thanks!

**Updates:**

I changed a little bit the $payload for the create_custom_token function:

```
  $payload = array(
      "iss" => $service_account_email,
      "sub" => $service_account_email,
      "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      "iat" => $now_seconds,
      "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
      "uid" => $uid,
      "email" => $email,
      "email_verified"          => false,
      "claims" => array(
        "premium_account" => $is_premium_account,
        "email" => $email,
        "email_verified"          => false,
      )
    );
```

and I also made some test to see it the token passed to firebase contains all the needed data. I decoded the encoded token with the same library (firabase/php-jwt) on my back-end and seams to be OK but firebase still create the user without email address.

[image]

I don't know what I am missing :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with custom tokens to do so.

The node.js Admin SDK allows you to create/updateUser and mint the custom token for that user. This would be the ideal way to do it but as you are using php, I recommend the following solution:

You will have to set the email using the client side js library:

- After minting the custom token, send it the client app along with the email. You are already sending it anyway, just pass the email along with it.
- In the client app, signInWIthCustomToken and the on the user returned updateEmail with the email provided as follows:

  ```
  firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
    .then(function(u‌​ser) {
      return user.updateEmail(email);
    }).catch(...)
  ```

Comment: Take a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth. I followed the official guide from Firebase and as you can see I get the user created but without email or provider, just with an UID

Comment: Yes, I understand. Modify and add the following to update the email (you will have to send it back to the client along with the custom token): firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(function(user) {return user.updateEmail(email);}).catch(...)

Comment: Thanks! that worked! Can you please update the answer in order to confirm it as correct. By the way, is this the correct way to do it with Custom Authentication System or it's better to use some server side library and create the user from server using Firebase Admin SDK? In my case using php I didn't find any lib to to that until now.

Comment: I added the code snippet to my solution. Somehow it didn't apply it in the format I selected. Anyway, as you said, ideally the node.js admin library allows you to createUser/updateUser with the email specified. You would then mint a custom token which on client signInWithCustomToken will sign in the user with the email set without the need to manually set it on the client. Until the same functionality is provided for php, you would have to do it this way. I personally think both cases are valid. Make sure you catch the error in case the email belongs to another account.

Comment: I check for duplicate emails in my laravel back-end. I tried to add the same user with the same email and firebase it's not thrown any error, it's just create another user with different uid and without email. Or I also can make .catch() after user.updateEmail(email) like user.updateEmail(email).catch()? Anyway thanks for your help. I will dig more into all this.